# Calling Location Manager twice in a service in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call location manager twice in my service.

First it will call the Manager onStart and then I am putting a timer for 20 seconds and I am calling it again.

The first time it is working but the second time after 20 seconds the location manager is not called at all..

Below is the code that I have tried:

```
     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
  {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.e("Location1", "Inside onStart");

    t = new Timer();

    locationFirst = "First";

    talker = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,locationListener);
}

            public void testMethod()
         {
    //Declare the timer


       //Set the schedule function and rate
              t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.e("Time",""+time);
            time += 1;
            String todis = String.valueOf(time);


            if(todis.contains("20"))
            {
                Looper.myLooper();
                Looper.prepare();

                talker.speak("Testing Service inside 20 in a App",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
                locationFirst = "Second";
                locationTocall();
                time = 0;
                t.cancel();

            }

        }

              }, 0, 1000);


            }


    public void locationTocall()
 {
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    location.requestLocationUpdates(location.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000,  10,locationListener);
          }


   private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
    {
        Log.e("Location1", "Inside MyLocation");

        String longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()); 
        String latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());

        String s = latitude+"\n"+longitude;

        Log.e ("Location1", " "+s);

        location.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    if(locationFirst.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRST"))
        {           
            testMethod();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

min distance for location update in your case is 10 metres
maybe because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a call to `timer.start()` in your `onStart` method.